# Create a Android Download bar using Retrofit 2 and 3 OkHttp

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I would like to know if you can create a progress dialog to show the progress of json data download. If there is a call to the server where it returns a huge json object and would like to show the progress.
I am using the Retrofit 2 and OkHttp 3.
I saw [this content](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/Progress.java) and found it interesting but do not know if you can apply it in my case.
In this example it uses a Progress class to a call on a txt, but in my case step date parameter and time on the server to get get the json and print Console values are wrong:

> bytesRead = 12224 contentLength = -1 done = false
>   -1222400% done

Comment: your server apparently does not return you the total length, so you can't show a progress bar indicating how far you are gone.

Comment: Sometimes the total length is unknown, for instance if the server generates the content on the fly. In such case, `-1` is returned.